# AP Div Pushing image

Tags: css, html, margin

I have placed an AP Div on my page that holds an iframe. I used position: relative so that the AP Div would not move with the image behind it. Once I added the AP Div with the css property Position: Relative it stays exactly where I want it , however it pushed the image further down. i need the main image to be aligned to top. If you look at the other pages you will see how they are all aligned at top. Is there a solution for this? I am not a css expert so I would be very appreciative of any help given. thanks!

my link is:

http://www.mylittleovertures.com/continue.html

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The basic problem is that `div` and `iframe` are block elements on the same level. Setting the iframe positioning to relative doesn't help. Instead, you should wrap image and iframe into a container DIV, set this DIV to `position:relative` and then absolutely position the iframe on that DIV. You could even drop the extra img tag and set the image as the background of the container DIV. You could also get of the `<center>` by setting the container DIV's `margin` to `0 auto`

Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/99wCg/3/

Comment: Thanks so much!I will put this into effect now. Thank you for taking the time to answer my question.

Comment: I implemented your suggestion and now my site is working great. I am studying the code to better understand how things relate to each other so I actually KNOW how to do it next time and not just a quick solution. I read about the wrapper and container div before you answered but it was greek to me and didn't know how to apply it to my coding.  I don't really like to do web I like to stick to graphic design, and I tend to believe some things you need to leave to the experts. But it doesn't hurt to learn from your mistakes and gain a little knowledge along the way.. Thanks again.